# Qual è l'origine dell'espressione "bufala"?

Tags: word-meaning, etymology, phrase-origin

Mi sono trasferita da qualche anno in Svizzera nel cantone italiano. Quando parlo con degli italiani spesso mi capita di sentire il termine "bufala".

Ho chiesto e mi hanno detto che vuol dire “bugia”, o fake news. Ma io so anche che è un animale. Non capisco come siate arrivati dall'animale all’espressione che significa “bugia”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benvenuta su Italian Language Stack Exchange!

Con il termine bufala, più precisamente, si vuole indicare una bugia travestita da informazione vera (un esempio di bufala mediatica sono i post di [lercio](https://www.lercio.it)), principalmente messa in circolazione per creare disinformazione e talvolta scalpore.

> Poiché la mozzarella di bufala è a Roma particolarmente apprezzata, la metafora deve fare riferimento non a questo formaggio, ma al malcostume, messo evidentemente in opera da qualche ristoratore romano disonesto, di spacciare la carne di bufala per la più pregiata vitella.
>   (Paolo D’Achille, Antonella Stefinlongo, Anna Maria Boccafurni: *Lasciatece parlà. Il romanesco nell’Italia di oggi*. Roma, Carocci, 2012, p. 287).

Una possibile origine della nascita di quest’espressione è riportata in questo stralcio:  infatti, il termine può far riferimento alla disonestà dei ristoratori che, prendendo in giro i clienti, gli vendevano una carne diversa da quella da loro ordinata. Potremmo così dire che gli servivano una vera e propria “bufala” :)!

Invece, secondo il Vocabolario della Crusca, l’espressione deriva da “menare al naso come una bufala”, prendere per il naso e portare in giro come si fa con i buoi, che avendo l’anello al naso, si lasciano tirare e trasportare senza opporre resistenza.

Pensando alla situazione odierna, dove la gente crede a tutte le “bufale” che legge, regge il paragone tra il bufalo, facilmente domabile e la massa, le persone che, senza interrogarsi della veridicità dei fatti, credono a tutto ciò che li circonda.

Spero di essere stata esaustiva, per ulteriori spiegazioni ti lascio alcuni link utili:
[Wikipedia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufala); [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/bufala-mediatica_%28Lessico-del-XXI-Secolo%29/); [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/questa-risposta-bufala).

Comment: Quello che hai messo dopo "stralcio:" è una citazione del libro che hai menzionato?

Comment: Grazie mile! Molto interessante che esiste un sito dedicato appositamente alle buffale. Molto bella è anche la stria dell'origine!

Comment: Attenzione: “Lercio” è un sito satirico; è sbagliato definire “bufale” le loro spiritosaggini, che piacciano o meno. Una bufala è un errore o una falsità voluta, non una inventata a fini umoristici o satirici. Sarebbe come dire che un romanzo è una bugia, perché i fatti che narra non sono reali.

Comment: @DaG mea culpa, hai ragione. Sta di fatto che comunque alcuni articoli potrebbero sembrare veri: infatti moltissime persone li condividono pensando che siano veri.

Comment: Per favore, cercate di mantenere il discorso civile e di non riempire i commenti con discussioni off-topic. Se volete discutere di altri argomenti, andate [nel Bar Sport](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11367/bar-sport). Inoltre uno dei principi fondamentali di SE è che i downvote sono personali: a patto che non siano "targeted", ognuno è libero di usarli per esprimere il proprio disaccordo.

Comment: @Marybnq: Di solito si usa il "blockquote" per le citazioni  (per questa ragione avevo modificato il tuo post). Penso che perlomeno il testo si dovrebbe mettere tra virgolette.

Comment: @Charo no, hai messo un blockquote in una mia frase (“infatti...”) nella citazione l’ho messo io.

Comment: @Marybnq: OK, scusa, avevo pensato che si trattasse di una citazione.

Comment: @Charo non ti preoccupare

Answer (score 3):

Sul sito dell'Accademia della Crusca puoi trovare una spiegazione dell'origine del termine [bufala](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/questa-risposta-bufala):

> Stando al GRADIT di De Mauro, l'uso figurato di bufala sarebbe
>   attestato dal 1960 e deriverebbe dal romanesco e tale datazione risale
>   a Claudio Quarantotto, che riporta un esempio di Gianfranco Calderoni,
>   che parla di «un film che, anche prima di essere visto, fu definito
>   una "bufala" dagli amici romani». Paolo D'Achille, oltre ad aver
>   segnalato un'attestazione anteriore dell'uso figurato di bufala,
>   all'interno di uno sketch di Nino Manfredi nella Canzonissima del 1959
>   (Fusse che fusse la vòta bbona), ne ha proposto una spiegazione
>   convincente. **Il significato figurato di bufala avrebbe avuto origine
>   in ambito gastronomico, non con riferimento alla mozzarella di bufala,
>   ma alla carne; alcuni ristoratori romani disonesti, infatti, avevano
>   il malcostume di spacciare la carne di bufala invece della più
>   pregiata carne di vitella; di qui il termine avrebbe assunto il valore
>   di 'fregatura' e quindi di 'notizia falsa**' e di 'produzione
>   artistica/cinematografica scadente'.

ed inoltre:

> Ho l'occasione di presentare qui un ulteriore dato: recentemente mi è
>   capitato di parlare dell'argomento con un anziano parlante romano, che
>   mi ha ricordato un fatto che accadeva proprio a Roma, intorno agli
>   anni Quaranta. **All'epoca le donne erano solite portare, per
>   risparmiare, delle scarpe con le suole in pelle di bufalo/bufala,
>   invece del più costoso cuoio; capitava, nei giorni di pioggia, che con
>   tali calzature si scivolasse, anche con considerevoli conseguenze;**
>   quando una donna infortunata arrivava al Pronto Soccorso (l'allora CTO
>   della Garbatella), il personale d'ospedale, considerata l'alta
>   frequenza dei casi, usava l'espressione **"Ecco un'altra bufala"**
>   (indicando la paziente metonimicamente con la causa del suo incidente:
>   'un'altra scarpa in pelle di bufalo aveva provocato nuovamente una
>   brutta caduta').

Riassumendo:

> Possiamo, in conclusione, rispondere ai nostri lettori che l'accezione
>   figurata di bufala, sia come 'notizia falsa' sia come 'produzione
>   artistica di scarso valore', è relativamente recente e ha sicuramente
>   origine a Roma, anche se è stata registrata solo tardivamente nella
>   lessicografia romanesca.